# Django admin not working with custom auth backend

Tags: python, django, authentication

I've a custom user model and an authentication backend.
When I'm using shell the authentication function works fine but when it comes to Admin site login, it is just not working.

The code comes from [Official Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example)

### settings.py

```
# Authentication
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'BBUser.UserInfo'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'BBUser.models.AuthBackend',
    'BBUser.models.AdminAuthBackend',
]
```

### models.py

```
class UserInfo(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    openid = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, unique=True)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    ...

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'openid'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    ...

    objects = UserManager()


class AdminAuthBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, openid=None, password=None):
        print "custom auth"
        login_valid = ('100' == openid)
        pwd_valid = ('tobeno.2' == password)
        if login_valid and pwd_valid:
            try:
                user = UserInfo.objects.get(openid=openid)
            except UserInfo.DoesNotExist:
                user = UserInfo(openid=openid, password='get from .py')
                user.is_staff = True
                user.is_superuser = True
                user.save()
            return user
        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return UserInfo.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except UserInfo.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

As I've put a `print` in AdminAuthBackend.authenticate(), so I know when it is executed.

When I'm invoking `authenticate()` from shell, the custom auth method is invoked while in admin page, it is not.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer myself.

After digging into Django's source code, I find this snippet in `django.contrib.auth.forms` that handles the post request from admin site's login form:

```
def clean(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

    if username and password:
        self.user_cache = authenticate(username=username,
                                       password=password)
        if self.user_cache is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['invalid_login'],
                code='invalid_login',
                params={'username': self.username_field.verbose_name},
            )
        else:
            self.confirm_login_allowed(self.user_cache)

    return self.cleaned_data
```

Notice that although it uses `auth.authentication` to handle the login action, it actually parses fixed fields `username` and `password`, which means the default admin site login form neglects your own AuthenticationBackends.

To solve this, I need to implement my own login-form for admin site.

Comment: Thanks! I took a different approach and ended up making `authenticate` more flexible by allowing `username` and `password`:
`def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, key=None):
        if key is None:
            # use username/password to log in an admin
            pass
        # my original code below
`

Answer (score 5):

This is my solution.. hope it will help someone:

```py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend' #add this line
    'your auth backend'
]
```

the default [django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend](https://github.com/django/django/blob/876dc0c1a7dbf569782eb64f62f339c1daeb75e0/django/contrib/auth/backends.py#L31) class is retained to ensure the default username / password authentication workflow used by the django administration. Then your custom authentication back-end class is added, so you can make your changes.

Comment: Hi :),Please provide a little more description to your solution.

Comment: for some reason not true for mine. it skips ModelBackend and goes to my custom backend. This is even though I have a custom user class but the request from Admin still uses user and password. i think the first answer here is the only solution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same issue when using a custom model with email authentification. I manage to solve this issue by creating  a new backend class. 
From what I understand, django is looping over all the backends defined in your application checking if any has the exact import paramaters.

In you case, maybe something like that will work

```
class EmailAdminBackend(ModelBackend):
def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
    UserModel = get_user_model()
    try:
        # Check if the user exists in Django's database
        user = UserModel.objects.get(openid=username)
    except :
        return None
    if user.check_password(password):
        return user
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it is late answer, it can help someone:
How you customize the authentication backend it doesn't matter. But one thing you should remember in mind that you have to include ModelBacked in AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS. Otherwise you can't login to your django admin.

Now your AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS should look like:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'BBUser.models.AdminAuthBackend',
    ]
```